# Fetch within an array of hashs a specific value ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have this json.

```
{"schedule"=>
   "schedule_layers"=>
    [{"name"=>"Layer 1",
      "rendered_schedule_entries"=>[],
      "rendered_coverage_percentage"=>nil,
      "id"=>"ABC123",
      "start"=>"October3",
      "end"=>nil,
      "rotation_virtual_start"=>"October4",
      "rotation_turn_length_seconds"=>500000,
      "users"=>
       [{"user"=>
          {"id"=>"11111111",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Micheal.Chi",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"22222222",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Ash.A.Basha",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"33333333",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Ven.Doli",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"44444444",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Abby.Silly",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}}],
     {"name"=>"Layer 2",
      "rendered_schedule_entries"=>[],
      "rendered_coverage_percentage"=>nil,
      "id"=>"BHD432",
      "start"=>"November4",
      "end"=>"November5",
      "rotation_virtual_start"=>"November4",
      "rotation_turn_length_seconds"=>600000,
      "users"=>
       [{"user"=>
          {"id"=>"5555555",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Hart.Shu",
           "self"=>nil,
           "html_url"=>nil}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"66666666",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Man.Sam",
           "self"=>nil,
           "html_url"=>nil}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"77777777",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Lie.Sigh",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PRW1P1J",
           "html_url"=>"https://target.pagerduty.com/users/PRW1P1J"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"88888888",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Cry.Bye",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/users/P9WCM8S",
           "html_url"=>"https://target.pagerduty.com/users/P9WCM8S"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"99999999",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Man.Lan",
           "self"=>nil,
           "html_url"=>nil}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"00000000",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Large.Hurry",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PEA0OXF",
           "html_url"=>"https://target.pagerduty.com/users/PEA0OXF"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"12345678",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"James.Harden",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PFOE8GN",
           "html_url"=>"https://target.pagerduty.com/users/PFOE8GN"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"8765321",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Tommy.Tucker",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PAPSIMG",
           "html_url"=>"https://target.pagerduty.com/users/PAPSIMG"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"0101010",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Code.Re",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/users/P8AVASJ",
           "html_url"=>"https://target.pagerduty.com/users/P8AVASJ"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"21212121",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Manny.Spinny",
           "self"=>nil,
           "html_url"=>nil}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"41414141",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Snit.Cimen",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PPTMCT1",
           "html_url"=>"https://target.pagerduty.com/users/PPTMCT1"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"52525252",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Dian.Ost",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PAOJEX4",
           "html_url"=>"https://target.pagerduty.com/users/PAOJEX4"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"65656565",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Kev.Shy",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/users/P6YK4Y4",
           "html_url"=>"https://target.pagerduty.com/users/P6YK4Y4"}}],
      "restrictions"=>[]},
     {"name"=>"Layer 1",
      "rendered_schedule_entries"=>[],
      "rendered_coverage_percentage"=>nil,
      "id"=>"P6VKKZX",
      "start"=>"2017-10-09",
      "end"=>nil,
      "rotation_virtual_start"=>"2017-10-08",
      "rotation_turn_length_seconds"=>500505,
      "users"=>
       [{"user"=>
          {"id"=>"78787878",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Lie.N",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"56565656",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Habibi Le",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"32233223",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Large.Pop",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"09090909",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Timmy.Nitt",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://target.pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"12435676",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Bri.Barry",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"10101010",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Dan Ostr",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"ABDUCDDD",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Ive.Chlong",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"OHGILKAS",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Jiff.Loss",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"AFRJIDN",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Levy Shy",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}},
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>"OFJDKANF",
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>"Patty Swice",
           "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/",
           "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/"}}],
      "restrictions"=>
       [{"type"=>"daily_restriction",
         "start_time_of_day"=>"08:30:00",
         "duration_seconds"=>120000}]}],
   "overrides_subschedule"=>
    {"name"=>"Overrides",
     "rendered_schedule_entries"=>[]
```

And I'm tasked with fetching only the summary under schedule => schedule_layers => users => user. This was my code for retrieving that data.

```
somefile = File.open("out.txt", "w+")
jdoc.fetch("schedule").fetch("schedule_layers").each do |jsonUser|
  somefile.puts jsonUser["users"][0]["user"]["summary"]
  somefile.puts jsonUser["users"][1]["user"]["summary"]
  somefile.puts jsonUser["users"][2]["user"]["summary"]
  somefile.puts jsonUser["users"][3]["user"]["summary"]
  somefile.puts "_" * 80
end
```

I realized that there the users hash had an array with so thats why I have those weird numbers. Regardless my text file shows this after running this code.

```
Micheal.Chi
Ashraf.A.Pasha
Ven.Doli
Abby.Silly
__________________________________________________________
Hart.Shu
Man.Sam
Lie.Sigh
Cry.Bye
__________________________________________________________

Lie.N
Habibi Le
Large.Pop
Timmy.Nitt
__________________________________________________________
```

I sorta understand why I'm only getting four from each section. But I want to find the real code in getting those values in the most beautifulest way.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why do you have such a large file for your example? Is it really necessary to included all those users? Please reduce it to the smallest size you can (two or three users, say) while retaining the essential structure. You need to also be more explicit on what you want the return value (a Ruby object) to be.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want, but I think this might be it.

```
somefile = File.open("out.txt", "w+")
jdoc.fetch("schedule").fetch("schedule_layers").each do |layer|
  layer["users"].each do |user|
    somefile.puts user["user"]["summary"]
  end
  somefile.puts "_" * 80
end
```

Use [each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) to iterate over every user object within each layer

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. All it did was return blanks, but I understand where you are coming from.

Comment: @M.Hajar hey I updated the sample. Didn't realize that there was an additional `user` nesting.

Comment: Amazing! You were right! I was wondering, since I'm new to coding, if you have any advice for learning how to be a good programmer like yourself?

Comment: Another question. If I wanted to only put the users that didn't have a nil in there self would it look something like this?

`layer["users"].each do |user|
 if ["user"]["self"] == nil 
    somefile.puts user
end`

I know this actually means, If I wanted to only put the ones that had nil as a value for the key self, but I have the right idea?

Comment: Two ways you could do it. If `self` is there, then print. Or, if `self is not empty` then print. So either `layer["users"].each do |user| if ["user"]["self"] somefile.puts user end` Or `layer["users"].each do |user| if !["user"]["self"].nil? somefile.puts user end`

Comment: Ah! I approached it differently. 'if user["user"]["self"] == nil
    else somefile.puts user["user"]["summary"].gsub(/\w+/, &:capitalize).gsub(/[.]/, ' ')
    end' But you way is way shorter. Thank you.